# Multi-device hybrid apps: typescript option for combining output JavaScript to file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Multi-device hybrid apps `CTP 2` and created a **`TypeScript > Multi-Device Hybrid App`** project. I need to combine my `TypeScript` compilation into a single javascript output file. I have a lot of typescript files... In an `MDHA` project I have the following properties page:

[image: MDHA project properties page]

If I add a project of type **TypeScript > HTML Application with TypeScript** I have the following options in the project properties page:

[image: HTML Application with TypeScript properties page]

which gives me the option to combine the output of `TypeScript` compilation into a single `JavaScript` output file.

Is there a way to compile into a single `JavaScript` output file? I know I can do this through a custom `MSBuild` step, but this is not what I want to do. I currently have all my compilation/minification etc configured with Grunt, but I want to see if MDHA can do the job...

Answer (score 0):

Option to combine JavaScript output to file is not supported for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (MDHA) for Visual Studio CTP2.0

Comment: Combining javascript output files could be solved using web essentials bundling, but problem is that web essentials bundling does not work in MDHA project.

Comment: Logged issue [link](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1429) for web essentials not working with MDHA

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a big mistake from Microsoft but we can hack the msbuild file. I will explain by steps what you should do.

1. Unload your project (right-click your project in solution explorer and click Unload Project)
2. Edit JsProj
3. add scripts/app.js to msbuild file in distribution section.
4. Reload your project
5. Build your project after that a combined file is created in folder scripts/app.js

For a detailed explanation check this link http://sharednode.wordpress.com/2014/12/30/cordova-ionic-typescript/